# Querying acts_as_votable records

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

I have used the acts_as_votable gem.

In the user.rb I have added

acts_as_votable
acts_as_voter

So each user can like another user.
A user can also create events.

In the index page for the events model I'd like to be able to show all the events that were created by users that you like.

`<% current.user.get_up_voted(@user).each do |user| %>` would display the users who have liked you so I thought I could so something like

```
if user_signed_in?    
 current_user.get_up_voted @user & something else 
end
```

With the something else querying who created the event.

But I'm struggling to think how I would construct a query like this. And whether I'm even on anywhere near the right track as anything I've tried so far just gives me an error.

Edit.

Sorry I better clarify what I'm asking about as I think you've misunderstood what I'm looking for.

I have a like button on a person's profile. I've got it set so that you like someone. What I want to be able to do is list the events that were created by the users you have liked.

It's a music site so it would be a list of musicians that interest you and then the events page could list all of the shows that they are performing in.

Answer (score 0):

---

### First get the items liked by others created by current_user and then show whether the user can vote or not

---

**user.rb**

```
    def all_events_liked_by_others    
      @events = Array.new
     ##assuming user has_many events
     ##for all events created by user(current_user)
      if self.events.present?
        self.events.reload.each do |e| 
        ##get only those events which are liked/voted
        if e.likes.count > 0
            @events << v
        end    
      end
      return @events.compact.flatten.uniq
    else
    return @events.compact.flatten.uniq    
  end
end##method ends
```

**get all events liked by others which are created_by current_user**

```
@events=current_user.all_events_liked_by_others
```

**in your view,show whether user has voted for that event**

```
 #### inside a for loop for @events
 <%if  current_user.find_up_voted_items.include?(event)%>
   You have voted for this event
 <%else%>
   You can vote for this event
 <%end%>
```